# shell script to find frequency of array elements

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to find the frequency of array elements.

`array=(111 111 222 111 777 555 666 777)`

I found this command:

```
(IFS=$'\n'; sort <<< "${array[*]}") | uniq -c
```

That prints:

```
3 111
1 222
1 555
1 666
2 777
```

But I want to print first the element of the array and next its frequency as a percentage, like this:

```
111 %
222 %
555 %
666 %
777 %
```

Comment: In the spirit of this forum, what is your question then? So you are not asking how to find frequency of elements in an array, are you asking how to reorder columns order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does what you asks for:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array=(111 111 222 111 777 555 666 777)

(
  IFS=$'\n'
  sort <<< "${array[*]}"
) |
  uniq -c |
    xargs -l1 bash -c '
pc=$(bc -l <<<"(100*$1)/$0")
LC_NUMERIC=C
printf "%s %02.02f%%\n" "$2" "$pc"
' "${#array[@]}"
```

`xargs -l1 bash -c`: Take each line and execute bash inline script with arguments.

The inline bash script itself:

```sh
# Receives the array size as argument 0
# The count as argument 1
# The value as argument 2

# Computes the percent with bc calculator
pc=$(bc -l <<<"(100*$1)/$0")

# Switches numeric format to C, POSIX
# so Bash printf "%f" can understand the output from bc
LC_NUMERIC=C

# Format the value and its percent frequency
printf "%s %02.02f%%\n" "$2" "$pc"
```

Sample output:

```
111 37.50%
222 12.50%
555 12.50%
666 12.50%
777 25.00%
```

Also much simpler with `awk`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array=(111 111 222 111 777 555 666 777)

(IFS=$'\n';awk '{arr[$1]++}END{for(k in arr)printf"%s %02.02f%%\n",k,(100*arr[k])/NR}' <<< "${array[*]}")
```

The `awk` script:

```
{
  # Populates an associative array
  # with argument 1 as key, and occurrences counter as value
  arr[$1]++
}

# Once the lines are parsed
END {
  # Print and format the associative array
  # with its key and the percent frequency
  for(k in arr) {
    printf "%s %02.02f%%\n", k, (100*arr[k])/NR
  }
}
```